# remove duplicate entry from html input boxes in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp1ahzew/1/) which checks for any duplicate entry entered in html input boxes.

It works in a way that if any duplicate entry is entered in a newly added row or the rows which are already there then the *alert message* **"duplicate"** is displayed.

I have used the following script in order to make that happen.

```
$('input[name*="code"]').each(function() { 
  $(this).change(function(){ 
    let value = $(this).val();
    let count = 0;
    $('input[name*="code"]').each(function() { 
      if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() == value) {
        count++;
        if (count > 1) { alert('duplicate');   }
      }
    });
  });
  $(this).addClass('e');
});
$('#addRow').on('click', function(){
    $('input[name*="code"]:not(.e').each(function() { 
      $(this).change(function(){ 
        let value = $(this).val();
        let count = 0;
        $('input[name*="code"]').each(function() { 
          if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() == value) {
            count++;
            if (count > 1) alert('duplicate');
          }
        });
      });
      $(this).addClass('e');
    });
});
```

What I am **trying to achieve now** is when any **duplicate entry** is entered in html input boxes then it should get disappeared automatically and the text "Please enter different text" left to the row should be displayed, something like this 
http://jsfiddle.net/zHJSF/

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('input[name*="code"]').each(function() { 
  $(this).change(function(){ 
    let value = $(this).val();
    let count = 0;
    $('input[name*="code"]').each(function() { 
      if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() == value) {
        count++;
        if (count > 1) { 
            alert('duplicate'); 
            ($(this).val()).stop(false,true).after('&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:red;" class="error">Please enter different text</span>');
            $('.error').delay(600).fadeOut();
            $(this).val('');  
        }
      }
    });
  });
  $(this).addClass('e');
});
$('#addRow').on('click', function(){
    $('input[name*="code"]:not(.e').each(function() { 
      $(this).change(function(){ 
        let value = $(this).val();
        let count = 0;
        $('input[name*="code"]').each(function() { 
          if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() == value) {
            count++;
            if (count > 1) { 
            alert('duplicate'); 
            ($(this).val()).stop(false,true).after('&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:red;" class="error">Please enter different text</span>');
            $('.error').delay(600).fadeOut();
            $(this).val('');  
           }
          }
        });
      });
      $(this).addClass('e');
    });
});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the script above so that it get rid of any duplicate entry entered in the html input boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This should work. It will get the input values and put them into an array, then check if the value exists in the array.

**javascript**

```
$('input[name*="code"]').each(function() { 
   $(this).change(function(){
      let element = this;
      var array = $('input[name*="code"]').map(function() {
         if (this != element)
            return $(this).val()
         return null;
      }).get(); 
      if (array.includes($(this).val())) {
         $(this).val("");
         $(this).attr("placeholder", "Please enter different text");
         $(this).addClass("error");
      } else if ($(this).hasClass("error")) {
         $(this).removeClass("error");
      }
   });
   $(this).addClass('e');
});
```

**css**

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: it looks good. I have integrated your code in the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/7d93ha2j/2/ and its working in the way I am looking for. I am seeing one minor issue. In the 1st row, if I change **CACN** to **CHPC** then the code in 2nd row gets disappeared which is wrong. The **code** in the 1st row should disappear.

Comment: It looks good. I am wondering why did you use `$(this).val("");` inside the if block in the script ?

Comment: I am wondering whats gonna happen if we don't add this `$(this).val("");` in the script ?

Comment: What I am thinking is, it will make the input box empty where duplicate code is entered.

Comment: @flash just to delete the input and show the placeholder value. You dont have to do it that way. I missed the part where you were adding a `<span>` after it to show the warning.

Comment: I usually opt against errors that have fade away after a delay because I dont think they are as user friendly. If you want that you can just remove the block after `if (array.includes($(this).val()))` and add your original code back in where you add the `<span>` after the input.

Comment: I am fine with the way you did it. Thank you. I will let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: I have a similar question in which I don't want code to remain empty. This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/x8e714rn/9/.

Comment: Should I test this on form submit or when the document is loaded ?